# How to delete message in discord.py in python 3.10 (nothing else works)

Tags: python, discord.py

I have tried anything in the internet and nothing works. My code:

```py
@bot.command() 
async def bug(ctx, bug):
    deleted_message_id = ctx.id
    await ctx.channel.send(str(deleted_message_id))
    await ctx.send(ctx.author.mention+", you're bug report hs been reported!")
```

I use python version 3.10

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [ask] and explain: how do you use the code? What happens when you try doing that? How is that different from what is supposed to happen? What does "tried anything in the internet and nothing works" actually mean - how did you try to search for answers, what web pages did you find, and how did they fail to solve the problem? Do you actually *understand* the code examples that you're finding? Please don't just copy and paste things. Some day, someone will harm your computer or data (or steal it) like that.

Answer (score 0):

To delete a message use the .delete() method.

```py
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    await message.channel.send("Deleting message!")
    await asyncio.sleep(3) #optional - sleeps for 3 seconds
    await message.delete()
```

If you want to delete a message the bot sent after x amount of time you can use the delete_after kwarg.

```py
@client.command()
async def foo(ctx):
    await ctx.send("This message will be deleted in 2 seconds", delete_after=2)
```

Comment: If I may add, `await ctx.message.delete()` in `client.command()` deletes the author's original command message.

Answer (score 0):

Simple delete command you can use. I added an if that checks if `amount` is more than 0 (because deleting 0 messages doesn't make sense)

Also, since `limit = amount_to_delete + 1`, it will delete the typed command without going to affect the total amount.

Note: if you want to delete messages, please use .purge() instead of .delete(), since it might cause weird deletion to happen

```py
async def purge_messages(ctx, amount_to_delete: int = 0):
    if amount_to_delete < 1 or amount_to_delete > 100:
        await ctx.send('You need to enter a value between 1 and 100')
    else:
        await ctx.channel.purge(limit=amount_to_delete + 1)
```